# Visual Studio 2019 color coding defaults changed?

Tags: visual-studio

It seems that the color coding of my Visual Studio 2019 suddenly changed. When I check the settings in Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Font and Colors and then for example User Members - Methods, I see that it no longer has a foreground color. My colleague with the same VS has this set to Olive.

I was happy with the default settings, and I'd rather not spend hours to replicate the default settings as they used to be. So what changed this color scheme, and how do I get it back? The first picture shows color coding like it was, the second how it is now (I hate it).

[image: Correct color coding like it used to be]

[image: Lost color coding]

Comment: This may be due to the new version of Visual Studio is change, I think your VS already auto updated.

Answer (score 1):

Why do I often find the answer after days of searching, and then after posting the question to SO?

At Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Advanced scroll down to end, at "Editor Color Scheme" there is a combo box which was set to Visual Studio 2017. It should be Visual Studio 2019 to get the colors back.

I still don't understand why this automagically changed though.

Comment: This is also very useful in VS2022. It appears that also there, sometimes, the color scheme automagically changes.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to disable "Use enhanced colors for C# and Basic" in Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Advanced?

Comment: I must be blind, but I cannot find this option :-(

Comment: Glad to see you found the answer, in another setting :-)

Answer (score 0):

For me there was an issue when I updated to version ~17.2.26. All the colors got blend and barely visible. Removing extensions, returning to default settings or safe mode changed nothing.

What helped was upgrade to 17.3. This applies to 2022, though.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the settings Environment -> General -> Color Theme. If you see "Use system settings" color scheme may be missing. Change VS Color Theme on Dark, Light or somethin different and [use answer rolandow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62634475/2517686)